# Read a number as single characters in r

Tags: r

I have an input file which looks like

```
222222222224444444444444444477777777777723548464646
233333333224444444444444444477776666667723545864646
```

When I read it into r with the Read table command **R** thinks it is a single number in 1 column. However, I would need to have a column for each single character

```
2 2 2 2 2   2

...
```

Is there a way to do this in** **R?

Comment: Does the file consist of just a single row of numbers?

Comment: there are multiple rows I edited the file..but each row shoudl be kept in a row and just split into the columns as described

Answer (score 3):

You can treat it as a fixed width file, and open with `read.fwf`, giving the `width` argument a vector of `1`s the same length as the (maximum) number of characters per line:

```
read.fwf("yourFilename", rep(1, chars))
```

where `yourFilename` is the name of your file, and `chars` is the number of characters per line (51 in your example).

If any rows have less characters than the `chars` value you set, they will be given the value `NA`

Comment: I think this is the best answer, the other's are just tricks to handle the data afterwards.

Comment: This implies that the file is o fixed width file ... which is not stated anywhere?

Comment: They ask for "a column for each single character", which to me means "fixed width file with each column of width 1".

Comment: Why do you assume equal number of columns per row?

Comment: It wasn't specified by the OP, but it's a sensible assumption since the example should represent the larger dataset.

Comment: EACH ROW HAS THE SAME NUMBER OF CHARACTERS,  would i give the widt argument the length of each row in the input file?

Comment: Additionally, for me (R3.0.2 on Ubuntu) the code above will give `NA` for missing values anyway. @OP, yes, for the example above, you would replace `chars` with `51`

Comment: Surprisingly, this is a really slow answer :(

Comment: @PascalvKooten, why is this surprising? I think it's pretty well-known that `read.fwf` is not particularly fast. For these types of things, I think a lot of R users typically look into something like `sqldf` + `substr` as an alternative to `read.fwf`.

Comment: Because Fortran's method of fwf is really blazingly fast, and since R can use Fortran, I assumed it would be fast.

Answer (score 2):

First, it might be easiest to read in the data with `readLines`. Then you can use `strsplit` to easily separate each string (sequence of numbers) into single digits.

Here's an example (I first write out the dummy data to a temporary file, `f`):

```
cat('222222222224444444444444444477777777777723548464646
233333333224444444444444444477776666667723545864646', file=f <- tempfile())
d <- readLines(f)
apply(do.call(rbind, strsplit(d, '')), 2, as.numeric)
```

The last line of code is firstly splitting each line of your text file into single characters, then binding each separated string into a `data.frame` (with `do.call(rbind, ...)`). Finally, we coerce it to numeric. You could leave it as `do.call(rbind, strsplit(d, ''))` if you're happy to leave the object as character data.

See `?strplit` for more info.

Comment: It's handling the data twice (reading in and then transforming), it is not advised.

Comment: @PascalvKooten I agree that `read.fwf` provided by @ping is simpler code, but as to your copied-and-pasted comment, why is it not advised? I think you'll find that `read.fwf` employs `readLines` anyway.

Comment: I believe fortran uses this kind of setting. Fortran is also really fast at reading. So I'm assuming since R can make use of fortran, it might be doing something like that instead. Also, there is something like readChar right? I'm pretty sure this would be slower.

Comment: Added the very unexpected benchmark results, my apologies. That fwf actually seems really broken (at least on my settings, Ubuntu 13.04, R.3.0.1)

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking the time to check it out - good to know. Makes me wonder whether any other relevant checks and balances are benig performing that I hadn't considered here...

Comment: I guessed that `readLines` wouldn't be deciding any `colClasses` or looking for comments, so `read.fwf` could be improved by `colClasses="character"` and `comment.char=""`, but this seemed to slow it down!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the really unexpected benchmark results (my apologies, jbaums):

For just the 2 lines offered:

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min        lq   median        uq      max neval
 jbaums()  265.131  290.2255  307.573  349.1005 1793.644   100
    fwf() 1627.021 1700.5955 1791.578 1986.1865 4910.790   100
```

For 3000 lines:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 jbaums()  33.50519  38.47324  41.33132  47.05635  85.21228   100
    fwf() 671.91310 693.56500 707.83914 724.06571 799.11987   100
```

This actually means that you shouldn't use the fixed width format, it is actually extremely slow.

Answer (score -1):

Will this do the trick?

```
unlist(strsplit("123", split=""))
```

Comment: This example would be better with some additional explanation.

Comment: It's handling the data twice (reading in and then transforming), it is not advised.

Comment: Don't know about others, but I usually read in, analyse and then transform the data to the format and structure that is needed 99% of the time. Only after that process is stable will I normally merge or bypass the read in and/or transform.

Comment: Sorry that the example is missing additional explanation, but basically it is in essence what jbaum suggested (1 minute before me) stripped down to the workhorse function in the do.call parenthesis which splits strings after each character (split="" does that) plus unlisting the result list that you receive from strsplit().